# Tensorflow: How to set tensor shape after reading image from tfrecord file for data augmentation?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tfrecord, image-preprocessing, tf.data.dataset

I have a `tf.data.Dataset` that I read from a `tfrecords` file like so:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# given an existing record_file

raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(record_file)
example_description = {
        "height": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        "width": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        "channels": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        "image": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    }
dataset = raw_dataset.map(
    lambda example: tf.io.parse_single_example(example, example_description)
)
```

Next, I combine the features into a single image like so:

```py
dataset = dataset.map(_extract_image_from_sample)

# and

def _extract_image_from_sample(sample):
    height = tf.cast(sample["height"], tf.int32) # always 1038
    width = tf.cast(sample["width"], tf.int32) # always 1366
    depth = tf.cast(sample["channels"], tf.int32) # always 3
    shape = [height, width, depth]

    image = sample["image"]
    image = decode_tf_image(image)
    image = tf.reshape(image, shape)

    return image
```

At this point, any image in the dataset has shape `(None, None, None)` (which surprises me, because I reshape them).
I believe this to be the cause of error, when I try to augment the dataset using `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator`:

```py
augmented_dataset = dataset.map(random_image_augmentation)

# and

image_data_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=45,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    shear_range=5.0,
    zoom_range=[0.9, 1.2],
    fill_mode="reflect",
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True,
)

def random_image_augmentation(image: tf.Tensor) -> tf.Tensor:
    transform = image_data_generator.get_random_transform(img_shape=image.shape)
    image = image_data_generator.apply_transform(image, transform)
    return image
```

This results in the error message:

```sh
TypeError: in user code:
    # ...
    C:\Users\[PATH_TO_ENVIRONMENT]\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\image_data_generator.py:778 get_random_transform  *
        tx *= img_shape[img_row_axis]

    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *=: 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

However, if I don't use graph mode, but eager mode, this works like a charm:

```py
it = iter(dataset)
for i in range(3):
    image = it.next()
    image = random_image_augmentation(image.numpy())
```

This leads me to the conclusion that the main error is the missing shape information after reading in the dataset. But I don't know how to define it more explicitly than I already do. Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of augmentations are you looking to do?

Comment: Have a look at the third code block: random rotation, shifts, shear, zoom, and flips (for now).

Comment: You should check out some of Chris Deotte's work, he provides some awesome code to do transformations when fetching tfrecord image data --> https://www.kaggle.com/cdeotte/rotation-augmentation-gpu-tpu-0-96

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Definitely some interesting approaches in there. However, they are not directly related to my question and do a lot more manually, than the approach above. The idea is to really make use as much as possible of the predefined methods of tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`tf.py_function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function) to wrap the preprocessing function that requires the tensors to have a shape like so:

```py
augmented_dataset = dataset.map(
    lambda x: tf.py_function(random_image_augmentation, inp=[x], Tout=tf.float32),
    num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
)

# and

def random_image_augmentation(image: tf.Tensor) -> tf.Tensor:
    image = image.numpy()  # now we can do this, because tensors have this function in eager mode
    transform = image_data_generator.get_random_transform(img_shape=image.shape)
    image = image_data_generator.apply_transform(image, transform)
    return image
```

This worked for me, but I'm not sure whether it's the only or even best solution.